# Can Lightning Email Templates call cross object merge fields?

Tags: email, email-template, merge-field, winter21, lightning-email-template

Salesforce recently released a new version of the [Lightning Email Templates](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_pardot_eilex_email_content_builder.htm) promising [Email template editor that don't suck](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZPIQA4).

I've tried to find any documentation relating to calling the cross object formula fields e.g.

```
{{{Opportunity.Contact__r.Phone}}}
```

but that is not possible.
Only by doing

```
{{{Opportunity.Contact__c}}} (Assuming Contact__c = Lookup(Contact) in opportunity field)
```

The email will show only the Opportunity.Contact__r.Name

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nope. You'll need visualforce (classic) email templates to go cross object.  You can always create formula fields to bring the data down to the same object

Comment: Apparently you can use Cross object merge fields in Classic but it won't be exposed https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spring 21' Salesforce release version,

Cross object formula fields are not available for **Lightning Email Templates**

Best Workaround is to use Classic Email Templates -> **Visualforce Email Templates** (Text classic email template also can't expose cross object fields)

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Lightning Email Templates are Useless" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">

<p>Account Name : {!relatedto.Account.Name}</p>
```